# How to call a selected index changed event in page load in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a asp calendar view in which i am generating dynamic control on the selected index changed of the calendar date. So i am facing a problem of post back as the dynamic controls are dispersing after click so i need to call this selected index changed event into the page load so the dynamic controls retain their state

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime sDate = new DateTime();
        sDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
        sDay = sDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string doc = ddlDoctor.SelectedValue.ToString();
        DataTable dt = tsbll.GetAvailableSlotsbyDocAndDate(doc, sDay);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Button label = new Button();
            label.Text = dr["SlotTime"].ToString();
            //label.Style["Left"] = "20px";
            label.CssClass = "btn btn-primary";
            //label.CssClass = "background - color: #19bc49;";
            label.Click += new EventHandler(labelClick);
            pnlLabel.Controls.Add(label);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.ToString()); }
}
```

Comment: If you haven't nothing to do in the exception handler, then do not catch the exception.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the way you're handling Exceptions is pointless. If you add nothing new to the exception object, then don't even bother re-throwing it.

Comment: You dont have to call the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler in `Page_Load`. You have to call a method that generates the dynamic controls. This method can be called from `Page_Load` and the event handler.

Comment: As Tim said, move this functionality into a separate method so it can be re-used by both the page_load and the selectedindexchanged event handlers. Then from both places you can call the same piece of code. This is a fairly basic principle code re-use.

Comment: Actually i have not completed with my code, i will pass the exception message later.Thank You,

Comment: Here the problem i was facing was I am using a dynamic buttons which are generated on the click of a asp calendar date and i want to write code on the click event of the dynamic control But now when i click on the button the button disapeares.  Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to call the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler in `Page_Load`. You have to call a method that generates the dynamic controls. This method can be called from `Page_Load` and the event handler.

```
protected void GenerateDocSlotLabels(string doc, DateTime day)
{
    string sDay = day.ToShortDateString();
    DataTable dt = tsbll.GetAvailableSlotsbyDocAndDate(doc, sDay);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Button label = new Button();
        label.Text = dr["SlotTime"].ToString();
        //label.Style["Left"] = "20px";
        label.CssClass = "btn btn-primary";
        //label.CssClass = "background - color: #19bc49;";
        label.Click += new EventHandler(labelClick);
        pnlLabel.Controls.Add(label);
    }
}
```

Now call this from both event handlers. For example:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime sDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    string doc = ddlDoctor.SelectedValue.ToString();
    GenerateDocSlotLabels(doc, sDate);
}
```

...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DateTime sDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
   string doc = ddlDoctor.SelectedValue.ToString();
   GenerateDocSlotLabels(doc, sDate);
}
```

Side-note: i have removed your `Catch` because it did nothing useful. Rethrowing an exception should be done with `throw` not `throw ex` to preserve the original stacktrace.

Comment: Thank You, I was just not thinking well tho.

Comment: Here the problem i was facing was I am using a dynamic buttons which are generated on the click of a asp calendar date and i want to write code on the click event of the dynamic control But now when i click on the button the button disapeares.  Please help...

Comment: @KhaleelR: have you used the `Page_Load` code which i have used before my last edit(with `is(!IsPostBack)`)?

Comment: @KhaleelR: well, currently you don't even need the `Calendar1_SelectionChanged1` event handler because the code is already executed in `Page_Load`. It's redundant

Comment: Yes I changed it, now the problem is i need to double click on the calendar to show the dynamic controls.